# data frame is_null returning wrong result

Tags: python, dataframe

I am using a python templating engine and saving the rendered code to run_cmd.py. I run this python script through a subprocess. In this template I load from a csv file to pandas dataframe. From subprocess I get the dataframe as a string. I now want to check if the dataframe that was loaded have missing values or not. So, I read the string using read_csv using StringIO. Now the dataframe looks like this:

```
           Name       City Country  Years
0  0        abc          X      US      1
1  1       abcd          Y      US      5
2  2       abde          Z      US    NaN
```

On checking for null values on this dataframe, I get False which is not correct. Any ideas what is going wrong?

```
code =  env.get_template('load_df_from_csv.template').render(path = 'xyz.csv')
with open("run_cmd.py", "w") as fh:
    fh.write(code)
    fh.close()
temp = subprocess.check_output(['python', './run_cmd.py'])
str_data = StringIO(temp)
df = pd.read_csv(str_data, index_col = False)
missing_value = df.isnull().values.any()
```

Comment: in parenthesis, When you use `with open` you don't need `close` file.

Comment: I can't replicate this issue. Creating a dataframe looking like that, `df.isnull().values.any()` returns `True` here.

Comment: New observation: I am seeing this issue with pandas version 0.19.2 and not with 0.13.1.